# Is it ok to charge a 12v battery with an AC to DC adapter and an solar charge controller?

Tags: battery-charging, solar-charge-controller

I don't have solar panel. I want to charge a 12v battery from the power supply on the wall. My plan is connecting an adapter (AC 240v to DC 12v) and a solar charge controller to charge the battery. Is it a safe solution?

Comment: what is the chemistry of the 12 V battery?

Comment: Solar charge controllers (at least the common ones for lead acid) are almost universally, buck converters. Which means they are designed to work with solar cells providing a higher voltage, like 18 or 20V. So I don't think a 12V DC source will work, you 'll need at least 15 or maybe better 18V.

Comment: @jsotola 12v 7ah Lead Acid

Comment: that battery requires a charging voltage of between 2.3 V and 2.45 V for each cell

Comment: @jsotola Thanks. By charging voltage, do you mean the voltage difference between the output DC voltage of  the adapter and the battery voltage?

Comment: no ... the voltage that is applied between the negative and the positive terminals of the battery ... a six cell battery would need 14.7 V